# Responsive layout managing percentages

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, grid

I'm trying to make my own responsive layout using percentages. I managed to calculate the columns that I wanted to use but I can't work out how to put like a margin (gutter) in between columns. If you check the codepen code there is no spacing in between the contents.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qIgby)

```
   .container{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*background: #333;*/
}


 .container .columns{
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 0 0 1em ;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    border-left-width:12px;
    }

    .row{
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .container .columns.col-1 { width: 8.33333333333%; }
    .container .columns.col-2 { width: 16.6666666667%; }
    .container .columns.col-3 { width: 25%;   }
    .container .columns.col-4 { width: 33.3333333333%; }
    .container .columns.col-5 { width: 41.6666666667%; }
    .container .columns.col-6 { width: 50%;   }
    .container .columns.col-7 { width: 58.3333333333%; }
    .container .columns.col-8 { width: 66.6666666667%; }
    .container .columns.col-9 { width: 75%;   }
    .container .columns.col-10{ width: 83.3333333333%; }
    .container .columns.col-11{ width: 91.6666666667%; }
    .container .columns.col-12{ width: 100%;  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally shy away from Calc as it's still not fully supported but up to you — http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

I would recommend wrapping all of your content in another set of elements that way you can use padding for spacing and margin for alignment. Check out the demo.

```
<div class="columns col-6"><div>6</div></div>
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iancwoodward/UT7tb/1/)

Comment: Ohh I didn't know about the calc limitation I thought it'd be supported by old browsers.

Comment: Yeah, it's a really cool concept but in real world most people need ie8 support as sad as it is. You could poly-fill it by falling back to calculating with JQuery but that's a bit messy and unnecessary.

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for could you mark it fixed? Or if you're looking for something else please detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving padding give margin

```
.container .columns{
float: left;
background: #ccc;
margin: 0 0 1em ;
margin-right: 1em;
margin-left: 1em;
border-left-width:12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc()` method to calculate margin from width.For example for `.col-3` the CSS would be

```
.container .columns.col-3 { 
width: calc(25% - 5px);
margin-right:5px;
}
```

make sure you use calc() in right way like this

```
calc([first value][space][operator][space][second value])
```

Comment: I just tried it too and still breaks the columns though. I tried reducing the columns width but i don't think that's a best practice. *please use the codepen above to try any suggested methods*

Comment: @nCore This solution seems fine just distribute the margin evenly on both right and left to make it centered.Take a look at this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IGLnz

Comment: @Mohammad Hamza & Froient
Cool, perhaps I tested it wrong myself. My apologies been trying to find a solution and got frustrated. Thanks.

Comment: Secondly you can use % for margin too. `.col-3` width and margin both would be set to %. That is `.col-3{width:23%;margin:0 1%;}`

Comment: nCore can you please describe what you actually want. Do you want to create margin between these columns?

Comment: Well your method works already, I've only wanted the margin in between columns so I can see each sections clearly. And like RWD frameworks they have this margin as well (I think they refer it as gutter). Basically just trying to replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you see your columns width, You have divided 100% of the viewport width equally.

For example:

```
.container .columns.col-6 {
   width: 50%;
}
```

So in that case, you won't have any space between two blocks.

So while mentioning the width for the columns, you need to consider margin as well.

so you can use either of the following two approaches:

```
.container .columns.col-6 { 
   width: calc(50% - 10px); // 10px represents the margin / space
   margin-right:10px;
}
```

or

```
.container .columns.col-6 { 
   width:  46%;
   margin-right: 1%;
}
```

The first approach is better.